# Close Program when Compiling with gcc

Tags: c

i have a program for multiply matrix.

```
for(y=0; y<1; y++) {
for(sy=0; sy<ni; sy++){
    ia = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*N*N);
    ib = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*N*N);
    ic = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*N*N);
    random_bil_integer(ia, ib, ic, psize);
    for(i=0; i<psize; i++)
            for(j=0; j<psize; j++)
                for(k=0; k<psize; k++)
                    ic[i*psize+k] += (ia[i*psize+j] * ib[j*psize+k]);
    free(ia); free(ib); free(ic);
}       
for(py=0; py<nf; py++){
    fa = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*N*N);
    fb = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*N*N);
    fc = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*N*N);
    random_bil_float(fa, fb, fc, psize);
    for(i=0; i<psize; i++)
            for(j=0; j<psize; j++)
                for(k=0; k<psize; k++)
                fc[i*psize+k] += (fa[i*psize+j] * fb[j*psize+k]);
    free(fa);   free(fb);   free(fc);
}
}
```

When i compile it with gcc, and run the output, the program  has force close.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dynamically allocated arrays are not big enough. For instance, `ic` has size `psize`

```
ic = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*psize);
```

but

```
ic[i*psize+k] += ...
```

`i*psize+k` is bigger than `psize`.

I guess you need

```
ic = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*psize*psize);
```

etc.etc.

You also have a problem with uninitialised data. You are assuming that all your data is initialised to zero, but it isn't.

Comment: content for psize = N * N, where N is 512. so the allocating space become ia=(int * )malloc(sizeof(int) * N * N);

Comment: @DwiKhairilOktahidayat Well if that is the case then your loop should say `for(i=0; i<N; i++)` and your formulas should say `ic[i*N+k] = `. One way or the other you've got yourself confused.

Answer (score 0):

all your arrays are undersized:

```
ia = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*psize);
```

is allocating space for `psize` integers (same issue for `float` arrays). You need a 2D array `psize*psize` so:

```
int matrix_size = sizeof(int)*psize*psize
ia = malloc(matrix_size);
```

and so on...

Comment: content for psize = N * N, where N is 512.
so the allocating space become 
ia=(int * )malloc(sizeof(int) * N * N);